# PLUpload Remove Files in FileAdded Event

Tags: javascript, plupload

I'm doing some file type checking in my Files Added event and under certain conditions I want the file removed from the upload queue.  I'm close, but not quite there.  Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
        var uploader = $("#html5_uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes : 'html5',
        url : '/valid/url',
        max_file_size : '5mb',
        unique_names : true,
        multi_selection : true, 

        init : {
    Init: function() {

    },
    FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
        plupload.each(files, function(file, i) {
        var id = file.id;
        var type = file.type;
        var checkType = type.match(/msdownload/g);
        if (checkType != null) {
            $('#' + id).find('.plupload_file_name span').empty().append('This file type is not allowed.');
            file.destroy();
            files = removeKey(files, i);
        } 
        });
        console.log(files);
        console.log(files.length);
        if (files.length>0) {
        // Start uploads immediately
        up.start();
        }
            },
        }
```

The removeKey method was something I picked up off of another discussion and looks like:

```
    function removeKey(arrayName,key) {
    var x;
    var tmpArray = new Array();
    for(x in arrayName) {
    if(x!=key) {
        tmpArray[x] = arrayName[x];
    }
    }
    return tmpArray;
}
```

As you can see, I want my files to uploaded immediately on add.

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of null
```

Likely because properties of the file I deleted are still trying to be read.  The end result is a "good" file won't get uploaded following a "bad" due to this error.  I'm likely not properly deleting the "bad" file.  Thanks.